# How fix InvalidPeer Error (Telethon ReportRequest)?

Tags: telethon

I am trying to send a report to spam using telethon.tl.messages.ReportRequest

```
entity = client.get_entity('username')
messages = [mes.id for mes in client.iter_messages(entity, min_id=2)]
report = client(ReportRequest(
                    entity,
                    messages,
                    types.InputReportReasonSpam(),
                    'spam message'
                ))
```

And I get the error **telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type and that the value is valid (for instance, bots cannot start conversations) (caused by ReportRequest)**

Comment: There are different requests for different types of peer/entity. Make sure the entity type is correct for your request, or use a different request.

Answer (score 0):

when registering a number in telegram, be sure to check the "contact synchronization" box . this is how I fixed this error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).